# How to install and setup lsp servers for vanilla emacs

Tags: package-repositories, lsp-mode, lsp

I wanted to install lsp-servers in emacs to allow my transition from VS-Code easier, however, when I tried to install lsp-mode from MELPA, I got the following issue:

`https://melpa.org/packages/markdown-mode-20230102.9.el: Not Found`

and the lsp-mode is not downloaded, is there something else that I have to do to install lsp-mode?

Also, I wanted to ask, is there a good way to copy errors like these? I was unable to copy-paste the error, and I had to remember the error, especially because when I switched over to StackExchange, the error disappeared and hence I had to re-run the command several times.

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure why you get this error, but anyway, a newer version of Emacs (29 or 30) will come with the [eglot](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/eglot.html) lsp-server built in. For older Emacs versions, eglot is available via ELPA, you might be interested to try it first.

Comment: For the error, switch to the `*Messages*` buffer and see if the error is recorded there. If so, you can cut-and-paste.

Comment: Update your package list with `M-x package-refresh-contents RET`, and try again.

Comment: @nega Thank you so much for your help, that seemed to solve the issue.